# How to get rowindex in Datagrid in Windows Mobile Application

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.1

I want to get row index of DataGrid in Windows Mobile Application Development.There is no property like Rowindex. Then how can we get rowindex.

Any one have idea? please share

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void test() {
  int rowIndex = dataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex;
  DataGridCell cell = dataGrid1.CurrentCell;
  Console.WriteLine("Current Row Number: {0}, Column Number: {1}", cell.RowNumber, cell.ColumnNumber);
  Console.WriteLine("Row {0}, Column 0 data: {1}", rowIndex, dataGrid1[rowIndex, 0]);
}
```